# Making change with minimum denominations with memoization

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was wondering how to make efficient algorithm with memoization. Particularly, is there a way to make O(1) access time for index value in Haskell?

Here is [the problem described in detail](https://github.com/phoxd/Making-change-with-minimum-denominations). And here is my attempt for recursive algorithm:

```
denom :: (Int, Int) -> [Int] -> Int
denom (_, 0) _ = 0
denom (0, _) _ = (maxBound :: Int) - 1000 -- subtracting 1000 otherwise overflows
denom (i, j) di
  | v > j = denom (i-1, j) di
  | otherwise = min (denom (i-1, j) di) (1 + denom (i, j-v) di)
  where v = di !! (i - 1)
```

Also, how would I declare `INFINITY` in Haskell so that `min` works in all cases?

Comment: You can get O(1) `!` by using an array instead of a list.

Comment: There exist [helper libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=memoization) if you do not want to code memoization yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to do `O(1)` access in Haskell, the standard go-to library is [Data.Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array.html).

Second, the general way to define something near a type but somehow "outside" it is to use the `Maybe` type; this is what I recommend for `INFINITY`. Also, I think that this makes more sense in the algorithm, because `INFINITY` really means "we can't make this value with this set of denominations", not "we can make this value with an infinite number of coins".

So using `Maybe`, the first thing we'll want to define is a version of `min` that works on `Maybe Int`:

```
myMin :: Ord a => Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
myMin (Just a) (Just b) = Just $ min a b
myMin Nothing x = x
myMin x Nothing = x
```

Then, using that we can attack this problem using the algorithm given in the linked page:

```
minCoinCoint :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
minCoinCoint target denoms = res (target, length denoms)
  where
    denomArray = listArray (0, length denoms) (0:denoms)
    myArrayBounds = ((0, 0), (target, length denoms))
    myArray = array myArrayBounds [(i, res i) | i <- range myArrayBounds]
    res (_, 0) = Nothing
    res (0, _) = Just 0
    res (t, d) = let dval = denomArray ! d
                     prev1 = myArray ! (t, d-1)
                     prev2 = if t >= dval
                             then (+1) <$> (myArray ! (t-dval, d))
                             else Nothing
                 in myMin prev1 prev2
```

And that's it. (well, assuming you remember the `import Data.Array` line at the top of the file)

Note that `myArray` is built by referring to `res`, and `res` makes all of its recursive calls by finding values in `myArray`.

This syntax might be a bit confusing:

```
(+1) <$> (myArray ! (t-dval, d))
```

That's done because remember that each element of `myArray` isn't an `Int` but rather a `Maybe Int`. That syntax says "apply the function `(+1)` to the inside of the value `(myArray ! (t-dval, d))`", so that a `Just 4` will become a `Just 5`, but a `Nothing` will remain a `Nothing`.

Comment: I realize that I swapped the order of arguments `(t, d)` from the page shown. I'm not going to go back and fix that unless people really find it confusing.